# Unable to publish the Azure Function

Tags: deployment, azure-functions

I have developed the Azure Function App One year back and published successfully and it's running. Now I have made a changes on functionality which is build succeed.

When I am publishing it's throwing error unable to publish.

[image]

I went through the path which showing screen shot showing below error.

> 14-09-2020 10.49.31 PM
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
> System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to
> determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more
> details.     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the
> output log for more details. <---
>
> System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to
> determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more
> details.
>
> ===================

I am unable to figure out the error here. Any one help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't stop because of this. And for the error you give us we can not get anything useful from it.

You just need to use another way to deploy. And it will give you the details error if it has any error.(Although I say it is another way, in fact they are essentially the same. VS Studio is actually performing packaging and running commands when you try to publish the azure function.)

Just do the following steps:

1, create the function app on azure.

2, build your function app on local.

3, Go to the compiled folder on local, and zip the content:

[image]

4, install the Azure CLI, then run `az login`.

5, cd to the compiled folder, then run below command:

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group yourresourcegroupnameonazure --name yourfunctionappnameonazure --src xxx.zip
```

After above steps, everything will be ok. This is the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar errors in two cases: locked files and previously deployment executed by DevOps pipelines. I don't know if it applies in your case. In both cases, you have to modify your Azure Functions settings on portal:

- case 1 : add MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES = 1
- case 2 : remove WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1